# Linux locale: en_US.UTF-8 vs en_US

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell, localization

I usually config my ubuntu via

```
sudo locale-gen --purge en_US.UTF-8
```

And I've the installed locales

```
# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Is it okay since I am missing `en_US`?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you're probably quite fine. Assuming `en_US.utf8` contains a UTF-8 American/English locale, it should work just fine. That's what I use myself:

```
% echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

If you run `locale -v -a`, it'll be a bit more descriptive:

```
% locale -v -a
locale: en_US           archive: /usr/lib64/locale/locale-archive
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    title | English locale for the USA
   source | Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  address | http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/
    email | bug-glibc-locales@gnu.org
 language | English
territory | USA
 revision | 1.0
     date | 2000-06-24
  codeset | ISO-8859-1

locale: en_US.utf8      archive: /usr/lib64/locale/locale-archive
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    title | English locale for the USA
   source | Free Software Foundation, Inc.
  address | http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/
    email | bug-glibc-locales@gnu.org
 language | English
territory | USA
 revision | 1.0
     date | 2000-06-24
  codeset | UTF-8
```

The only difference between `en_US` and `en_US.utf8` is that the former uses ISO-8859-1 for a character set, while the latter uses UTF-8. **Prefer UTF-8.** The only difference in these is in what characters they are capable of representing. ISO-8859-1 represents characters common to many Americans (the English alphabet, plus a few letters with accents), whereas UTF-8 encodes all of Unicode, and thus, just about any language you can think of. UTF-8, today, is a defacto standard encoding for text. (Which is why you should prefer it.)

Answer (score -3):

en_US.utf8 contains everything ASCII does but I don't think it covers any more than that.  Your system won't be able to print/view characters other than those and will display a box (or a box with a question mark in it) when it encounters one of these unknown characters.

Comment: Gonna explain why you got downvoted. en_US.utf8 means an english language interface/localization with unicode support. utf-8 supports far more than just ASCII.