# Is there a difference between en_US.utf8 and en_US.UTF-8?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, charset, localization

Server info (DNS and IPs removed):

```
cat /proc/version && uname -a && java -version

Linux version 2.6.16.33-xenU (*************) (gcc version 4.1.1 20070105 (Red Hat 4.1.1-52)) #2 SMP Wed Aug 15 17:27:36 SAST 2007
Linux ************* *************-xenU #2 SMP Wed Aug 15 17:27:36 SAST 2007 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
java version "1.6.0_14"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_14-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

I have some PHP code that is reading from an Excel file and doing string comparisons. It is failing on the server due to what seems to be a locale issue. On my local machine (OSX 10.8.5 Mountain Lion) however, it works!

On my local machine the locale is en_US.UTF-8. On the server the locale was POSIX but I changed it to en_US.utf8 since there was no en_US.UTF-8 when I looked at *locale -a* (interestingly, the list of locales on the server are all lower case but on my Mac they are all upper case, which is where this questions stems from).

Is there a difference between the two that could affect string comparisons?

Also, as per [this SF post](https://serverfault.com/questions/605776/linux-locale-en-us-utf-8-vs-en-us) I ran *locale -v -a*. On the server, en-US.utf8 uses the UTF-8 codeset (I'm assuming this is the same as what I normally call charset?). However, on my local machine I seem unable to run the *locale -v -a* command, though *locale* and *locale -a* work fine.

**Edit:**
**[A related question I asked on StackOverflow.](https://serverfault.com/questions/616744/is-there-a-difference-between-en-us-utf8-and-en-us-utf-8)**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### TL;DR:

The codepage / character set `.utf8` in `en_US.utf8` is not officially recognised as far as I can tell.  There is no IANA `utf8` character set **name**. `utf8` is likely generated by `glibc` - see final heading.

The IANA character set name is `UTF-8`.

- The hyphen is important
- Case is **in**sensitive

Therefore, these are all valid:

- `en_US.utf-8`
- `en_US.UTF-8`
- `en_US.uTf-8`

There is also a !case-sensitive! **alias** for the **name** `UTF-8`, namely: `csUTF8`.

Therefore, this would also be valid:

```
en_US.csUTF8
```

But I have never seen this in the wild.

### The details, with chapter and verse

`UTF-8` is a valid IANA character set **name**, whereas `utf8` is not. It's not even a valid **alias**.

POSIX.1-2017, section [8.2 Internationalization Variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_02) says:

> If the locale value has the form:
>
> ```
> language[_territory][.codeset]
> ```
>
> it refers to an implementation-provided locale, where settings of language, territory, and codeset are implementation-defined.

Here the part in question is the `[.codeset]` part, which POSIX doesn't define, but IANA does.

For the character set defined by RFC2978: `UTF-8, a transformation format of ISO 10646`, the
[IANA Character Sets](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) lists the **name** as:

`UTF-8`

and the note at the top says:

> These are the official names for character sets that may be used in
> the Internet and may be referred to in Internet documentation.

An **alias** `csUTF8` is provided, about which [RFC2978 IANA Charset Registration Procedures, section 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2978#section-2.3) says:

> All other names are considered to be aliases for the
> primary name and use of the primary name is preferred over use of any
> of the aliases.

[IANA Character Sets](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) also says:

> The "cs" stands
> for character set and is provided for applications that need a lower
> case first letter but want to use mixed case thereafter that cannot
> contain any special characters, such as underbar ("_") and dash ("-").

In the `cs` alias, the case is significant (while the name is defined as case insensitive, above).

Given the alias `csUTF8`, `en_US.csUTF8` would also be valid, but I have never seen this format in the wild.

While case matters in **aliases**, regarding **names**, [IANA Character Sets](https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml) says:

> The character set names may be up to 40 characters taken from the printable characters of US-ASCII. However, no distinction is made between use of upper and lower case letters.

So while `en_US.utf-8` is valid (a lowercase version of the listed `UTF-8`), `en_US.utf8` doesn't refer to a IANA character set as it drops the `-`.

#### If it's not IANA, where does `utf8` likely come from?

[glibc's `_nl_normalize_codeset()`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/intl/l10nflist.c#L330-L334) does the following:

- Only passes characters or a digits (goodbye hyphen)
- Converts characters to lowercase

  ```
  for (cnt = 0; cnt < name_len; ++cnt)
    if (__isalpha_l ((unsigned char) codeset[cnt], locale))
      *wp++ = __tolower_l ((unsigned char) codeset[cnt], locale);
    else if (__isdigit_l ((unsigned char) codeset[cnt], locale))
      *wp++ = codeset[cnt];
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed research!

Answer (score 0):

No difference. They are one and the same.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - do you have anything to support this? I realize it might just be a naming convention and there might be no docs. Thanks!

Comment: Its just a naming convention. Expand both into their human-lang equivs: 'United States English, using the UTF-8 Charset' == 'United States English, using the UTF-8 Charset'

Comment: @MatthewHerbst Well, "no difference" but look at the answer *that_should_be_accepted* by TomHale  and why you should use "en_US.UTF-8" anyway.

Comment: That is false on MacOS: There, `en_US.UTF8` fails, whereas `en_US.UTF-8` succeeds. The former is basically wrong, and glibc happens to correct it and hide a latent bug. I've recently ran into this issue.